# My short program stops responding after loop ends. Why?

Tags: c, loops

Here is my code:

```
printf("The current number is %d. Player 2, enter a factor.\n", number);
scanf("%d", &factor);
while (number % factor != 0) {
 //check if factor or not, but use "while" so it doesn't go all the way back to the start of loop
        printf("Invalid factor. %d does not evenly divide %d. Enter a valid factor.\n", factor, number);
        printf("The current number is %d. Player 2, enter a factor.\n", number);
        scanf("%d", factor);
}
while (factor == 1){
    printf("Invalid factor. Numbers less than 2 are not allowed.\n");
    printf("The current number is %d. Player 2, enter a factor.\n", number);
    scanf("%d", factor);
}
number = (number / factor); // same dealio as before

x += 1; // if the game doesn't end, it's player 1's turn
}
```

When I input an invalid factor for Player 2, and then input a valid one, the program stops responding. Can someone please explain why?

For example, if the initial number is 20, Player 1 inputs 6, and is given the proper error and the loop repeats until they give a valid factor, like 5. The program then progresses to Player 2.  The current number is now 4, but Player 2 inputs 6, and is directed into a loop until they choose either 2 or 4. Upon choosing a valid factor, however, the program stops responding. I don't know why.

The variables are all declared, they're just cropped out because the post can't be mostly code.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you have a potential divide by 0 issue --- consider what happens in the first `while` loop if the player enters `0`.

Comment: That's just a matter of changing the second while to (factor < 2).  Doesn't solve the overarching problem.

Comment: The second argument to scanf() (in both instances) should be &factor, not factor.

Comment: AHH! That's it! It was so simple.....  Thanks!

Comment: Adding the `-Wformat` warning flag will catch this error for you (on GCC and Clang).

Comment: lets run 4 as number into the above code:  ...  the modulo operation will only result in 0 for input values of  0 and 4  So eventually, player2 enters a 4. This results in the second while loop not being entered, so the division 4/4 = 0 occurs.   I.E. the 'hang' problem is NOT in the posted code.  however, probably the problem is in the result being 0

Comment: I recommend that you refactor your code, because now you read the number in 3 different places. Consider using a `do {} while()`-loop instead: first print the prompt, then read the value, then check and give proper error messages.